# C Programming - Cant print user input

Tags: c, loops, printing, scanf

I am very new to C and have an assignment due soon. I need to write a program that asks the user for many numbers and stops when the user types "0". Then show the numbers the user typed and how many even and odd numbers there were. Then add them all up. I need my to have `num=0` for my function to work but thats also the number that stop the while statement so the program ends up not even asking for an input and just stops right away. Can anybody help me with this? Any clues or guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getNumbers(int sumEven, int sumOdd, int num);

int main (void) {

int number_of_integers, sumEven, sumOdd;
char user_name[128];

printf("What is your name?\n");
scanf("%s", user_name);

printf("\nEnter any real numbers followed by ENTER.\n");
int num = 0;

while (num = 0) {
    scanf("%d\n", &num);
    if (num < 0)
        printf("<-Error: Please enter positive numbers!->\n");
}

num = getNumbers(sumEven, sumOdd, num);

printf("%s, the numbers you entered are broken down as follows:\n", user_name);
printf("%d" , num);

return 0;
}

int getNumbers(int sumEven, int sumOdd, int num)  {
    sumEven = 0;
    sumOdd = 0;

    if (num % 2 == 0)
        sumEven += num;
    else
        sumOdd += num;
}
```

Comment: Also, I am not able to use arrays yet because we haven't learned them

Comment: There are too many problems with your code. It will be good for you to get the basics right.

Comment: You can't show all numbers that user entered in after he enters 0, because you can't store them without arrays.

Comment: I heard that you can print them using a for loop without storing them I guess. Is that right? Or is it not possible without arrays?

Comment: `num = 0` sets `num` to `0`. Maybe you wanted `==`

Comment: You're already using an array. (`char user_name[128];`)

Comment: You're going to need to use pointers in `getNumbers()` for the interface to stand a chance of working.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, i ended up using arrays and everything works great now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the error in your code:

```
//while (num = 0) {
while (num == 0) {
    scanf("%d\n", &num);
    if (num < 0)
        printf("<-Error: Please enter positive numbers!->\n");
}
```